Defining Elements outside of component
I wonder if it OK to define the Elements outside of the components. Just something like this
const Element = <Component/>


const App = () => {

return <MemoizedParentComponent>{Element}</MemoizedParentComponent/>

}

So, the reason why I would like to do it is because MemoizedParentComponent uses React.memo under the hood and if we pass <Component/> as children prop directly, it causes the rerender whenever the App component is rendered (if it has some states for example).
So basically, as I see there are two options to support normal memorization:

define Element in useMemo inside the App component
define it outside of the App component like in the example above.

Are there any potential risks in defining the element outside of the component or it’s a legit option?

syntactically, you can do the 2. but it can not have dynamic props

Both options seem to work, but there is a difference between them which could be significant: things defined outside of a component are shared among instances of that component, like a static field in Java, while things wrapped in useMemo are private.
Whether it matters is reliant on how many instances of App are you going to create - if just one it doesn't matter, if more then it might be meaningful - this in turn is reliant on whether React modifies elements (the objects returned when you call components like this: <Component/>). Unfortunately I don't know if it does, it's an implementation detail, we shouldn't rely on it.
To summarise: use React.useMemo just to be safe.
Or you can use one of the solutions provided in a similar thread, check it out: how to use React.memo with a Component contains children
Be wary though: I think the accepted answer is not correct but I'm too lazy to actually check. I like the one provided by Maxime Bret suggesting to implement custom arePropsEqual funtion for React.memo of the MemoizedParent - if you can modify it, that's what I would probably do.
It could be implemented like this:
/**
 * Replicates default behaviour os `React.memo` for everything except
 * for `children` which are ignored.
 */
function arePropsEqual(prevProps, newProps) {
  for (const [key, prevValue] of Object.entries(prevProps)) {
    if (key === 'children') {
      continue; //ignore if children changed
    }
    const newValue = newProps[key];
    //comparing by `Object.is` is the default behaviour used by React.memo
    if (!Object.is(prevValue, newValue))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

which will be cool as long as the children don't have props. If they would, going deeper in prevProps['children'] vs newProps['children'] would be necessary.
